# Building model in H2o.AI on AWS throwing Out Of Memory Error

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, out-of-memory, h2o

We are running h2o on AWS and training a model with a 14gb CSV dataset on a GBM algo and it gets to 36% and then fails with error:

> 'Java heap space', caused by java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Here are the specs for our environment:

```
h2o Cluster Version: 3.17.0.4153
R Version: 3.4.3
java version "1.8.0_77"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_77-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.77-b03, mixed mode)
Algorithm: GBM
Training DataSet: CSV with 1000 cols, 2,695,297 lines, that is 14gb in size
AWS:
Model       vCPU    Mem (GiB)    Storage
t2.2xlarge  8       32           EBS-Only
```

Questions:

How much memory is required to train GBM on a dataset of this size?

Is there some configuration we can do to get h20 to manage memory better?  Eg; use available memory to a limit and then stream without crashing or something...

If it takes a long time and finishes at least you have a model. 
Really we just want something that won't fail... At the moment the only answer is try a smaller dataset... and every training attempt wastes time and money.

We are relatively new to this so any help is much appreciated.  If you need more details just let me know what you need.

Thanks for your time.

Update:

So we had our java option -Xmx set to 14g and we increased that to 25g and that allowed it to continue.

Comment: Can you show your code for `h2o.init()`, are you assigning enough memory there? Also can you use a newer version of h2o?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend 4-5x the dataset size.  So at least 64 gb.